# Name variable from string in Dash

Tags: sh, ksh, dash-shell

I need to set a variable name from a string.
Here is my code :

```
var="cle"
value="1"

printf -v $var "$value"

echo $cle
```

I want it to output "1"

I am getting:

```
illegal option "-v"
```

I tried to replace printf by the declare function but, dash doesn't include it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this in `dash` is to use `eval`, but that is risky unless you *know* that your string is a valid identifier.

```
expr "$var" : '[_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]\{0,\}$' && eval "$var=$value"
```

The call to `expr` fails (or at least, is intended to fail) if the value of `var` is anything other than a single valid identifier.

Comment: Thanks. `expr`outputs me the string length of `$var`. If I only enter `eval $var=$value"`, it works perfectly. I don't think the check might be necessary.

Comment: You can redirect the output of `expr` to `/dev/null` to ignore it; the important thing is that the exit status will be non-zero if the match fails, preventing `eval` from running. This avoids nasty surprises with something like `var="rm -rf /"`.